# Azure AD - no groups listed when setting Access Control in the portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I'm trying to do simple thing here - I want to grant Reader permissions for AppInsights resource in Azure Portal. So I created a security group called *Devs*. It has members in it (if that's important).

Now, I go to AppInsights resource => Access Control => Add, and look at this:

[image]

It can't find this group! Why is that?

Comment: how did you create the group?

Comment: In the portal: Azure Active Directory => User and Groups => All groups => New Group

Comment: @alvipeo can you find other users or groups in `select`?

Comment: No, no groups at all. Which is why I ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Azure Support, here's what happened - I log in to Azure Portal with an external user (user@outlook.com for example). Even though this user is a Global Admin he's not a Member of the tenant. So, either you log in with a user who's a member (@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) or you convert your user to be a Member (now, that requires you to log in as a Member admin). Here's the PowerShell script on how to convert:

```
Install-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user_outlook.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com -UserType Member

# just to check if you became a Member user
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user_outlook.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com | select usertype
```